# Ionic - LazyLoad Image, Only the first image from the array was display and the rest are still using the default image

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, npm

I need help on fixing this error, I know the problem but I don't know how to fix it or using different method.I use ng-lazyload-image(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazyload-image) for lazyloading. You can check my home.html and home.ts.

**Updated:** Thanks to **@August**, I change the code and the lazyload is working but there is still problem, only the first image from the array is shown after the lazyload and the rest of the image use default image instead of the image from the array. I need help on how to fix it.

[Error screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hn5uc33dwne5gq/error.jpg?dl=1)

[Image Slider View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a3LL.jpg)

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  NavController
} from 'ionic-angular';

export class HomePage {
  //Image Array
  imagesjan = [
    'page-01.jpg',
    'page-02.jpg',
    'page-03.jpg',
    'page-04.jpg',
    'page-05.jpg',
    'page-06.jpg',
    'page-07.jpg',
    'page-08.jpg',
    'page-09.jpg',
    'page-10.jpg',
  ];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content #container>
  <ion-slides loop="true">
    <!-- Image Slider-->
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of imagesjan">
      <img [defaultImage]="'assets/default.jpg'" [lazyLoad]="'notreallink.com/january/'+img" [scrollObservable]="container.ionScroll" />
      <p>dummy text</p>
    </ion-slide>

  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Instead of [lazyLoad]="'http://notreallink.com/january/{{img}}'" try:[lazyLoad]="'http://notreallink.com/january/'img" or [lazyLoad]="'http://notreallink.com/january/'+img"

Comment: The second option work but only the first page load and the rest are still using default image instead of the image from the array but thanks for helping.

Comment: have you found any solution ?